# Use format or regexp to convert -3.014-5 to scientific format -3.014e-5

Tags: regex, format, tcl

I'm fetching node coordinates from a file. Unfortunately for small numbers the following format is used:

```
-3.014-5
```

without an "e" --> -3.014e-5

I can't use format because all the functions I found require a floating point number, which the above not is...
So I wanted to use regular expressions to find the "-5" part and replace it by "e-5".
([+-]?[0-9]+)?$ would do that, but how can I use that expression in TCL?

```
set num -3.014-5
set Enum [ regexp -all { ([+-]?[0-9]+)?$ } $num ]
```

I get "invalid command name "+-", so I replaced the square brackets by " , but then I get 1 as an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you get the error message *"invalid command name "+-"*. As long as you have your regular expression inside curly braces `{}` the expression should not be evaluated by the interpreter.
For me this worked to achieve the desired result:

```
set Enum [regsub {^([+-]?[.0-9]+)([+-]?[0-9]+)?$} $num {\1e\2}]
```

**Edit:**
If you want "normal" numbers (those without an exponent) to remain unchanged you could simply remove the `?` from the tail part of the regular expression. In this case the expression will not match and the number remains unchanged:

```
set Enum [regsub {^([+-]?[.0-9]+)([+-][0-9]+)$} $num {\1e\2}]
```

Comment: Please forgive my clumsiness regarding regex, it's not my usual playground. I have solved it by creating this proc:              proc MakeE { In } {
  set Tail [regsub {^([+-]?[.0-9]+)([+-]?[0-9]+)?$} $In {\2}]  
  if {$Tail != ""} {
    set Out [regsub {^([+-]?[.0-9]+)([+-]?[0-9]+)?$} $In {\1e\2}]
    return $Out
  }
    return $In
}   How could I include this "If tail != """ directly in the regex?

Comment: If you want the input number unchanged if there is no *Tail* you could simply remove the question mark from the tail part of the regular expression - so the expression will not match and the number will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tcl but I would guess you need to escape the + and propably the - too.
Try this: `set Enum [ regexp -all ([\+-]?[0-9]+)?$ $num ]`
or this: `set Enum [ regexp -all ([\+\-]?[0-9]+)?$ $num ]`

You might need to use `\\` instead of `\` (I don't know tcl sorry)

Comment: Wrong. Just use curly braces. (`[]` is used for command substitution, so escaping that can work too)